# ASP.NET MVC3 C# - foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, foreach

I am confused as to how to implement the following in my current foreach:

```
@foreach
(var post in Model."table".Where(w => w.Private_ID == 1).OrderBy(o => o.Date))
{
  <div class ="post">
    <fieldset>
      <p class="post_details">At @post.Post_Date By @post.Username</p>
      @post.Post_Desc
    </fieldset>
  </div>
}
```

so that post.Username will NOT show if `@post.anon` is `TRUE` (and so that it will say "Anonymous")

Thanks in advance for any advice/help/suggestions.

Comment: it has a stupid name and I didn't want to embarrass myself :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
@(post.anon ? "Anonymous" : post.Username)
```

Though I would consider doing most of this logic in the C#, rather than leaving it to the view (therefore, creating a specific view model with all of the logic already done. Meaning you can just loop through and not have to do any additional thinking:

```
@foreach(var post in Model.Posts)
{
   <div class ="post">
      <fieldset>
         <p class="post_details">At @post.Post_Date By @post.Poster</p>
         @post.Post_Desc
      </fieldset>
   </div>
}
```

Where @post.Poster in the above example is already preset with anonymous if it is required.

Comment: I don't really like to put logic in the view, so I will take your advice, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@foreach(var post in Model."table".Where(w => w.Private_ID == 1).OrderBy(o => o.Date))
{
    <div class ="post">
        <fieldset>
            <p class="post_details">At @post.Post_Date By (@post.Anon == true ? "Anonymous" : @post.Username)</p> 
            @post.Post_Desc
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, the line should have said: @(post.Anon == true ? "Anonymous" : post.Post_Desc)

Comment: It's not working but I unserstand what it's trying to do.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Why post.Anon == true ?,  you can shorten that to:  post.Anon ?

Comment: Yes you can. Just post.Anon would be enough. It's a personal choice. I like to put == true explicitly for readability.